# Discrete Fourier transform of csc^2 sequence

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Consider finite sequence $x_j^k, j=0,...,k-1$:

$0, csc^2(\frac{\pi}{k}), csc^2(\frac{2\pi}{k}),...,csc^2(\frac{(k-1)\pi}{k})$

Suppose its discrete Fourier transform be

$X_j^k=\Sigma_{l=0}^{k-1}x_l^ke^{-\frac{2\pi lj}{k}}$

Interestingly $X_j^k$ has simple patterns:

$X_j^2 =1,-1$

$X_j^3 = 8/3, -4/3, -4/3$

$X_j^4 = 5, -1, -3, -1$

$X_j^5 = 8, 0, -4, -4, 0$

$X_j^6 = 35/3, 5/3, -13/3, -19/3, -13/3, 5/3$

$X_j^7=16, 4, -4, -8, -8, -4, 4$

...

Is there a way to calculate the formula of $X_j^k$ ?

Comment: I am going to give a partial answer. A liitle remark: your summation should be $X_j^k=\Sigma_{l=0}^{k-1}x_l^ke^{-\frac{2\pi lj \color{red}{i}}{k}}$ where $\color{red}{i^2=-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A step towards the solution**

I will use in the sequel capital $K,L$ instead of $k,l$ (lowercase $l$ is too similar with number $1$).

Let $f(t):=\csc(\pi t)^2=\dfrac{1}{\sin(\pi t)^2}$ which is computed on discrete values

$$\forall L, \ 1\leq L \leq K \ \ \ \ \ \ t=\dfrac{L}{K}.$$

Displaying the values of the Discrete Fourier Transform as curves, we observe discrete parabolas (see graphics below for values of $k$ between $4$ and $25$.)

After some computations, one obtains, in fact, quadratic expressions:

$$\tag{1}\forall L, \ 1\leq L \leq K \ \ \ \ \ \ \hat{f}(L)=2\left(L-\frac{K}{2} - 1\right)^2 - \dfrac{K^2}{6}-\dfrac{1}{3},$$

which take exactly the same values as the Discrete Fourier Transform of the given sequence, but without any proof for the moment.

---

**Edit:** as the result is a quadratic function + shifts, which are mapped to second derivation and multiplications by complex exponentials, it may be interesting to use **Inverse** Discrete Fourier Transform.

Another track: take advantage of the following identity:

$$\left(\dfrac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t}\right)^2 \times \dfrac{1}{(\sin \pi t)^2}=\dfrac{1}{t^2}$$

transformed, by Discrete Fourier Transform, into:

$$\underbrace{\Lambda(u)}_{triangle} \underbrace{\star}_{conv.} DFT(csc^2)(u) =DFT(\dfrac{1}{t^2})(u)$$

[image]

Comment: Hi Jean, I may not understand your answer. The formula $\hat{f}(L) = 2(L-\frac{K}{2}-1)^2-\frac{K^2}{6}$ seems not reflect the discrete Fourier transformed sequence. For example when $K=2$, $\hat{f}(0)=22/3$ and $\hat{f}(1)=4/3$ but they should be 1 and -1 separately. Could you give some explanations to the ansower? Thanks

Comment: There is a shift. You should, for a given $K$, not begin with $L=0$ but with $L=1$: you will see it is exactly the values you give. I see now that I have mistakenly make the values of $L$ begin at $0$. I correct it.

Comment: I am sorry, I have realized that a $-1/3$ term is missing. I correct it.

Comment: Are you working with Matlab ?

Comment: See the little edit I have added.

Comment: Jean, Yes I use Matlab FFT to get $\hat{f}$ for given $K$ and $L$.  Now the formula (1) indeed matches the values from Matlab FFT for given $Ks$ and $Ls$. I'm not sure whether what you did is to "fit" those values by induction? Is there any analytic way to get formula (1)?

Comment: What I did is assuming the existence of a formula $f(L)=aL^2+b^L+c$ and imposed 3 constraints to get 3 equations for $a,b,c,$ and then check it for numerous values. The problem remains to have a proof of this formula. I am going to write a second edit as a second possible track to obtain a proof.

Comment: In second edition I think what you mean is to substitute $DFT(csc^2)(u) $ with $aL^2+b^L+c$ in $\Lambda(u)\star DFT(csc^2)(u)$ to verify the left of equation is indeed in the form of $DFT(\frac{1}{t^2})(u)$?

Comment: It could be done that way...